# Moc Qt headers automatically using make

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, moc

I'm trying to moc all header files with Q_OBJECT macro using make. Here is what I have right now.

```
HEADERS = *.h
MOCS := $(shell grep -l Q_OBJECT $(HEADERS))    
MOC_SOURCES := $(MOCS:%.h=moc_%.cpp)
$(MOC_SOURCES) : moc_%.cpp: %.h
    @echo "Building Moc: $@ from $<"
    /opt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/gcc/bin/moc $< -o $@
```

But I have a problem in this solution. Only first file is moc'ing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first rule in the makefile has several targets, only the first target in the rule becomes the default goal, not the whole list.

Therefore, I believe you need to define an "all" target above dependent on the $(MOC_SOURCES).